# Facebook graph api find post from object_id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph API v2.5 : How can I find the post with object_id? Say I create a video with video_id, when I want to delete the video, also want to delete the post attached to it, how can I do that? I am thinking of /me/posts endpoint, but i can't filter the result to narrow down  the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who is looking for answer, my solution is to wait for 5 sec (sleep) after you create the video object, look through user's posts and find the post that has that object_id = video_id. The solution is optimized if we can limit the posts to be latest 5 posts then look up on that set.

Comment: What if more than 5 posts are created after your post by user?

Comment: Why to wait for `5 sec (sleep)`?

Comment: didn't think of the case user will post 5 posts in 5 sec. Like that just query all posts or at some values

Comment: And Why to wait for `5 sec (sleep)`?